# how to drop a replicated table in both the publication and subscription

Tags: t-sql, replication, sql-drop

How do I drop a replicated table in the publication as well as the subscription? (scripts only)

I do not want to remove it from replication only, because then an unreplicated copy of the table will remain on the subscriptions. I want all instances of the table removed.

So I want a script that removes a table from a publisher, and removes the table from the publication and also drops the table in the publisher and all subscribers. Ideally it would take a parameter of the table name.

Comment: What's with the down vote? I hate it when people randomly down vote without leaving any comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to call [sp_droparticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173832.aspx) or [sp_dropmergearticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179926.aspx) to delete the article from the publication, then generate a new snapshot.

Then call DROP table to delete the table at both publisher and subscriber(s).

This is covered in both [Add Articles to and Drop Articles from Existing Publications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493.aspx) and [Delete an Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146908.aspx).

To post the DROP statements to subscribers from the publisher, use [sp_addscriptexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174360.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but you misunderstand the question. Your solution requires access to the subscriber database in order to run the script. I am looking for a script to run on the publisher only that replicates the structural change over to the subscriber (without running any additional scripts)

Comment: Then you will need to look at sp_addscriptexec to post the drop statements to the Subscribers.  Otherwise, there is no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Please see this post: http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/executing-scripts-with-sp_addscriptexec/